# Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'evrz.account' in field list

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a trigger, but I get this error:

> Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'evrz.account' in field list

I tried to execute this:

```
INSERT INTO `record` (`record`.account_id) VALUES (289688082)
```

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `evrz`.`record_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `record` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF `evrz`.`account`.`status` ='OUT' in (
            SELECT `evrz`.`account`.`status`
            FROM `evrz`.`account`
            WHERE (account_id = NEW.account_id)
        )THEN
UPDATE `evrz`.`account` SET `evrz`.`account`.`status` = 'IN' WHERE (`evrz`.`account`.`account_id` = NEW.account_id);
END IF;
IF `evrz`.`account`.`status` ='IN' in (
            SELECT `evrz`.`account`.`status`
            FROM `evrz`.`account`
            WHERE (account_id = NEW.account_id)
        )THEN
UPDATE `evrz`.`account` SET `status` = 'OUT' WHERE (`evrz`.`account`.`account_id` = NEW.account_id);
END IF;

END
```

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
    `employee_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `mail` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()',
    PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `account` (
    `account_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `status` enum('IN','OUT') NOT NULL DEFAULT ''OUT'',
    `employee_id` int(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `record` (
    `record_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `creted_at` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()',
    PRIMARY KEY (`record_id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `account` ADD CONSTRAINT `account_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employee`(`employee_id`);

ALTER TABLE `record` ADD CONSTRAINT `record_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account`(`account_id`);
```

I am trying to make that when an employee logs in to a database, his stsus will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` statement can only refer to the row that's being inserted, using `NEW.columnName` to refer to a column in the new row.

When you're updating another table, use the `IF` function (or a `CASE` expression) in the value, and it can refer to the existing value in the row being updated.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `evrz`.`record_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `record` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE evrz.account
   SET status = IF(status = 'OUT', 'IN', 'OUT')
   WHERE account_id = NEW.account_id;
END
```